# WPF ContextMenu apprears on left side of the mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

Whenever I'm creating a ContextMenu it appears on the left side of the mouse instead of the usual right side for some reason. I'm not tweaking any settings in the ContextMenu object, all I'm doing is instantiating it, adding item(s) and setting IsOpen to true. I'm using MahApps.Metro, and the window also has a custom WindowChrome, but I don't this it has anything to do with this weird behavior. This had never happened to me before, and I hope that somebody can explain why this might be happening and how to I fix it.

This is my code:

```
ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();

MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
item.Header = "Add Category";
item.Click += (o, args) =>
{
    ...
};
ContextMenu.Items.Add(item);
ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
```

P.S. This is not caused because there is not enough room for the menu, I've tested it on the far left side of the screen.

Comment: Though its kind of unusual, try setting [ContextMenu.PlacementTarget](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Is the behavior specific to a code-created context menu or is it the same for a predefined xaml context menu?

Comment: Predefined menus didn't make a difference.

Comment: I've also tried setting the PlacementTarget and the values of Placement

Comment: Try setting `ContextMenuService.Placement` (e.g. `ContextMenuService.Placement="Right"`) instead of `PlacementTarget` or `Placement`.

Comment: Even weirder. This made the menu open in the upper-left corner of the screen.

Comment: I'm considering implementing my own CotnextMenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. All I had to do is change the Windows 10 Tablet PC Settings from Right-Handed to Left-Handed.